# Tkinter : Moving more than one object at once

Tags: python, object, tkinter, move

I am still fairly new to tkinter and I am trying to create a network simulator. I have made a simpler version of my program without all of the extra network stuff. I have been stuck on a problem for quite a while now. I can't work out how to make it so when I try and move one of the circles, it moves the text with it. I had an idea to delete the text when I click down so I can then move the object and recreate the text when I drop the object but I am not sure how to do this. Any other ideas are certainly welcome.

This is my library:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

#Window class for making different windows

class Window:

#Constructor
def __init__(self, window, colour="black", width=600, height=400):
    #Set variables
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.colour = colour

    #This dictionary is used to keep track of an item being dragged
    self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

    #Create canvas
    self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg=self.colour, height=self.height, width=self.width)
    self.canvas.pack()

    #Add bindings for clicking, dragging and releasing over any object with the "circledrag" tag
    self.canvas.tag_bind("circledrag", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.OnCircleButtonPress)
    self.canvas.tag_bind("circledrag", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.OnCircleButtonRelease)
    self.canvas.tag_bind("circledrag", "<B1-Motion>", self.OnCircleMotion)

#This is used to draw particle objects on the canvas, notice the tag that has been added as an attribute
def _create_circle(self, xcoord, ycoord, color):
    self.canvas.create_oval(xcoord-25, ycoord-25, xcoord+25, ycoord+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags = "circledrag")

#This is used to draw text on top of the object on the canvas
def _create_text(self, xcoord, ycoord, text):
    self.canvas.create_text(xcoord, ycoord, text = text, tags = ("circledrag", "text"))

#This uses the find_closest method to get store the x and y positions of the nearest item into the dictionary
def OnCircleButtonPress(self, event):
    #print self.canvas.find_withtag("Current")
    self.canvas.delete("text")

    '''Begin drag of an object'''
    # record the item and its location
    self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

#This clears the dictionary once the mouse button has been released
def OnCircleButtonRelease(self, event):
    '''End drag of an object'''
    # reset the drag information
    self._drag_data["item"] = None
    self._drag_data["x"] = 0
    self._drag_data["y"] = 0

#This moves the item as it is being dragged around the screen
def OnCircleMotion(self, event):
    '''Handle dragging of an object'''
    # compute how much this object has moved
    delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
    # move the object the appropriate amount
    self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
    # record the new position
    self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

class DragCircle:
#Constructor
def __init__(self, window, width=100, height=100, colour="red", text = "test"):
    self.window = window
    self.circle = self.window._create_circle(width, height, colour)
    self.circle_text = self.window._create_text(width, height, text)
```

and this is the main program:

```
from Tkinter import *
import my_module2

#Make a window from my own class
window = Tk()
window.title("Drag & Drop")

#Create an instance of the window class
main_window = my_module2.Window(window)

#Create a circle object from the DragCircle class
circle = my_module2.DragCircle(main_window)
circle2 = my_module2.DragCircle(main_window, 200, 200, "green", "hello")

#Start the animation loop
window.mainloop()
```

I would like to know how to move two objects at once.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I need to know how to move more than one object at once. I have a bit of an idea on how to do it like I said in the post but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: That's not really a question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show a minimal example of what you've tried, and be precise about the problem with it.

Comment: Alright... How do I move multiple objects at once on click? You can see what I have done in the code from the post.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect in your code.

Comment: there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226164/how-do-i-move-multiple-objects-at-once-on-a-tkinter-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you create a circle/text pair, create a unique tag and associate the tag with both the circle and the text. You can then use this unique tag to move both objects at once.

For example, modify your `DragCircle` constructor to look like this:

```
class DragCircle:
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, window, width=100, height=100, colour="red", text = "test"):
        self.window = window
        tag = "circle-%d" % id(self)
        self.circle = self.window._create_circle(width, height, colour, tag)
        self.circle_text = self.window._create_text(width, height, text, tag)
```

Next, modify the `_create_circle` and `_create_text` functions to accept the tag:

```
def _create_circle(self, xcoord, ycoord, color, tag):
    id_=self.canvas.create_oval(xcoord-25, ycoord-25, xcoord+25, ycoord+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags = ("circledrag", tag))

#This is used to draw text on top of the object on the canvas
def _create_text(self, xcoord, ycoord, text, tag):
    self.canvas.create_text(xcoord, ycoord, text = text, tags = ("circledrag", "text", tag))
```

Finally, modify your `OnCircleButtonPress` to get the tag and use it for moving the objects around:

```
def OnCircleButtonPress(self, event):
    ...
    item = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    tags = self.canvas.gettags(item)
    for tag in tags:
        if tag.startswith("circle-"):
            break
    self._drag_data["item"] = tag
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal which may not be the best

In the constructor you define an association table.

```
self.assoc = {}
```

add the method:

```
def _create_circlewt(self, xcoord, ycoord, color, text):
      tc = self.canvas.create_oval(xcoord-25, ycoord-25, xcoord+25, ycoord+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags = "circledrag")
      tx = self.canvas.create_text(xcoord, ycoord, text = text)
      self.assoc[tc] = tx
```

in the OnCircleMotion: add the line

```
self.canvas.move(self.assoc[self._drag_data["item"]], delta_x, delta_y)
```

just after the other move line

in DragCircle class constructor
comment your definition and add the call to _create_circlewt

```
self.circle_w_text = self.window._create_circlewt(width, height, colour,text)
```

it works .. I let you enhance the canvas move to enable multiple objects association like

```
self.assoc[CircleIndex].append(otherobjectIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution from [How do I move multiple objects at once on a Tkinter canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226164/how-do-i-move-multiple-objects-at-once-on-a-tkinter-canvas)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_oval(100, 105, 150, 150, tags="Bob", fill='light blue', outline='green')
canvas.create_oval(200, 205, 150, 150, tags="Bob", fill='light blue', outline='green')

for _ in range(50):
    canvas.move("Bob", 5, 0)
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)

root.mainloop()
```