# How do I move multiple objects at once on a Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code, which moves one of the two Tkinter `Canvas` objects. How do I make it move both at the same time using `canvas.move()`?

```
canvas.create_oval(100, 105, 150, 150, fill = 'light blue', outline = 'green')
canvas.create_oval(200, 205, 150, 150, fill = 'light blue', outline = 'green')

tkinter.update()

for x in range (1, 100):
    canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
    tkinter.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [*tags*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers).  You can tag your two objects similarly and then ask the canvas to move all objects tagged that way:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_oval(100, 105, 150, 150, tags="Bob", fill='light blue', outline='green')
canvas.create_oval(200, 205, 150, 150, tags="Bob", fill='light blue', outline='green')

for _ in range(50):
    canvas.move("Bob", 5, 0)
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221139/7430022